# How to count occurrences of specific element in multiple columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have this table in Excel:

[image]

I want to count number of zeros and ones in each row and put it in corresponding columns (`Number of ones`, `Number of zeros`)

So, for row 3: 
There are **3** ones and **no** zeros.
 
So in `column D` (**Number of ones**) will be **3** and in `column E` (**Number of zeros**) will be **0**.

---

How to achieve that using Excel formula in `D` and `E` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel you can use the COUNTIF Function to accomplish This.
In Cell D3 enter

```
=COUNTIF(A3:C3,1)
```

This first argument identifies the range A3 to C3... The second argument basically identifies what you want to count, in this case the number of ones.

Likewise to count the number of zeros....
In Cell E3 enter the formula

```
=COUNTIF(B3:D3,0)
```

You can then fill down the formula (By double clicking on the corner of the rectangular box)
[image: Excel Count]